# How to Get the HTML code to show only after the firebase query is loaded

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the JS of my angular JS webapp:

```
 .controller('rulesCtrl', ['$scope','$location',
 function($scope,$location){


 var uid = CommonProp.userUid();

 firebase.database.ref('users').child(uid).child("fullname").once('value', 
 function(snapshot){
 var users = snapshot.val();
 $scope.fullname = users;
   },function(err) {
    console.log(err);

});

 $scope.logout = function(){
 CommonProp.logoutUser();  
};
```

And below is the HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="rulesCtrl"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Dear {{fullname}},</h1>
            <p ng-show=""> <br>
            The Players are divided into 4 positions, "DEFENDER", 
           "MIDFIELDER", "FORWARD", and a unique role for the 
            particularly versatile players, "HYBRID".<br/><br><br/></p>
```

My Issue

My issue is that at times, the page often loads and the `{{fullname}}` code appears empty in the view although, an inspection in the console shows that a value is there.

Is there a way to make sure the contents of the `<p>` tags only show after the `{{fullname}}` resulting from my firebase query is resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the firebase code is outside of angular context so angular doesn't know the scope has changed when the firebase promise resolves

Try wrapping the scope assignment in `$timeout()` which when called will trigger a digest cycle by calling `$apply()` internally

```
firebase.database.ref('users').child(uid).child("fullname")
  .once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var users = snapshot.val();
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.fullname = users;
    });
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);

  });
```

Also be sure to inject `$timeout`